# Facebook permission screen shown for acquired permissions (SDK 3.0)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated the latest Facebook SDK in my app and have some issues with the authentication procedure.

At the first time everything goes as expected, the user gets the read permission dialog.

If the user accepts those permissions, then logs out and back in again, he/she will sometimes be prompted for the same read permissions again.

Why does it asks for these permissions again? Why does it only do this sometimes?

Comment: I am having same issue as well it's working fine if you have facbook app installed but for web dialog user is always prompted for this